# Como eliminar caracteres repetidos consecutivos con RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy tratando de hacer un ejercicio simple de Reg Expressions, y trato de eliminar  Simplemente errores de tipografia como por ejemplo:

```
Naaaaciiionalll
```

deberia quedar solo:

```
Nacional
```

Trate con esta, pero me elimina Solo algunas repeticiones como se ve aqui:

```
let str = "Nnnaaacioooonal"; 
let filtenetworking = str.replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)\1/gi, ""); 
console.log(filtenetworking);
// > "nacinal"
```

Alguien Puede ayudarme a resolver esto, soy nuevo y he estado tratando de aprender RegExp pero la verdad no lo domino muy bien.

Gracias de Antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
(.)\1+
```

Remplazar por:

```
$1
```

Utilizar búsqueda `case-insensitive` (flag `i`)

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/oQ1Xce/1/)

Con javascript:

```js
str = "Naaaaciiionalll";
result = str.replace(/(.)\1+/gmi, "$1");
console.log( result );

str = "EEeeesSssStttTo ees UuuunaAaa PpprrrRuUUUuebaAAaa";
result = str.replace(/(.)\1+/gmi, "$1");
console.log( result );
```

**Explicación:**

Tanto `\1` (en la búsqueda) como `$1` (en el remplazo) significan `primer grupo de captura`, referencian a lo encontrado dentro del primer conjunto de paréntesis `()`

Comment: Julio Esa funciona perfecto!!!...
Pero puedes explicarme que hace la parte luego de la `,` `"$1"`

Comment: Tanto `\1` (en la búsqueda) como `$1` (en el remplazo) significan `primer grupo de captura`, referencian a lo encontrado dentro del primer conjunto de paréntesis `()`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que ya no dirá "Nacional" por que la `a` está repetida, espero te puedas guiar

```js
var str = "Naaaaciiionalll";
let filtenetworking = str.replace(/(.)(?=.*\1)/g, "");
console.log( filtenetworking );
```